# MVC-5: Show Full Names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I would like to show a FullName from a computed property at the top of a view. I can see the FullName property when I look at the Autos log. But the lambda expression used in the Html helper only shows the property name, not the data. Is there any way to display the data that the log seems to show to be available?

UPDATE:

The Complete View:

```
@model IEnumerable<SlamJammersData.Model.Attendances>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Rosters";
}

<div class="container container-fluid">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="container">


                @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Attendances", FormMethod.Get))
                {

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p>
                                <h3>Attendances for player: @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FullName) </h3>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p>
                                <h4>Attendances Recorded: @Model.Count() </h4>
                            </p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                }

            </div>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Type)
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AttendanceDate)
                    </p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <p>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comments)
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
           @foreach (var item in Model)
           {
               <div class="row table-striped">
                   <div class="col-md-2">
                       <p>
                           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)
                       </p>
                   </div>

                   <div class="col-md-2">
                       <p>
                           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AttendanceDate)
                       </p>
                   </div>

                   <div class="col-md-2">
                       <p>
                           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comments)
                       </p>
                   </div>

                   <div class="col-md-1">
                       <p>
                           <input class="btn btn-xs btn-info" type="button" value="Details" onclick=" location.href = '@Url.Action("Details", "Attendances", new {id = item.Id}, null)' "/>
                       </p>
                   </div>

                   <div class="col-md-1">
                       <p>
                           <input class="btn btn-xs btn-info" type="button" value="Edit" onclick=" location.href = '@Url.Action("Edit", "Attendances", new {id = item.Id}, null)' "/>
                       </p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-2">
                       <p>
                           <input class="btn btn-xs btn-success" type="button" value="Add New Attendance" onclick=" location.href = '@Url.Action("Create", "Attendances", new {enrollments_Attendance = item.Enrollments_Attendance}, null)' "/>
                       </p>
                   </div>
                   <div class="col-md-1">
                       <p>
                           <input class="btn btn-xs btn-danger" type="button" value="Delete" onclick=" location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Attendances", new {id = item.Id}, null)' " />
                       </p>
                   </div>
               </div>


           }

        </div>
```

The Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? Id )
{
    //Get the rosters and their attendance records
    IQueryable<Attendances> attendances = db.Attendances
        .Where(a => a.Enrollments_Attendance == Id)
        .Include(e => e.Enrollments.Individuals)
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.AttendanceDate);

    ViewBag.EnrollmentId = Id;

    var sql = attendances.ToString();
    return View(attendances.ToList());
}
```

The Model:

```
namespace SlamJammersData.Model
{
    public class Attendances
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime AttendanceDate { get; set; }

        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Comments { get; set; }

        [Display(Name="Enrollments")]
        public int Enrollments_Attendance { get; set; }

        public virtual Enrollments Enrollments { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                var player = Enrollments.Individuals.FirstName + " " + Enrollments.Individuals.LastName;
                return player;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure if it is IEnumerable or not, but here is what is showing in the debugger:
[Screenshot of debugger's Auto log](http://www.dstroketennis.com/Portals/0/ScreenShots/Attendance-Debug-Auto.jpg?timestamp=1428299188487)

Comment: Your passing a collection to the view. `IEnumerable` does not have a property named `FullName`. Are you wanting to display one item or a collection of items?

Comment: Is the value of `FullName` always the same for all attendances?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke 
I want to display the one item that represents the parent to a list of child records.

Comment: You view has `@model IEnumerable<Attendances>` and `IEnumerable<T>` does not have a property named `FullName`. What do you mean the parent? (you don't pass the 'parent' to the view so how would the view know anything about it). Does `Attendances` contain a property named `FullName`?

Answer (score 1):

Since your model is `IEnumerable<SlamJammersData.Model.Attendances>` and `FullName` is a property of `Attendances`, you can't use `FullName` property outside `foreach` block like what you're trying to do. However assuming that the value of `FullName` is always the same, you can use `ViewBag`. Change your controller method as below

```
public ActionResult Index(int? Id )
{
    //Get the rosters and their attendance records
    IQueryable<Attendances> attendances = db.Attendances
        .Where(a => a.Enrollments_Attendance == Id)
        .Include(e => e.Enrollments.Individuals)
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.AttendanceDate);

    ViewBag.EnrollmentId = Id;
    ViewBag.FullName = ...; // logic to get FullName here

    var sql = attendances.ToString();
    return View(attendances.ToList());
}
```

and display the full name in your view as follows

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Attendances", FormMethod.Get)) 
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>
                <h3>Attendances for player: @ViewBag.FullName </h3>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>
                <h4>Attendances Recorded: @Model.Count() </h4>
            </p>
            </div>

        </div>
}
```

Comment: When I use
<h3>Attendances for player: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FullName) </h3>
I get a 'cannot be inferred from usage error in Intellisense.

Comment: I did edit it a few hours ago. I guess it hasn't been approved or something.

Answer (score 0):

I got an assist from the ASP.NET forum on this topic. The helper code line needed is:

```
<h3>Attendances for player: @Html.DisplayName(Model.First().FullName) </h3>
```

Thanks to everyone who took a look at this question.

UPDATE: I found a different line of code that works and seems a little safer.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ElementAt(0).FullName)
```

UPDATE:
I found that as Marko commented, there was an exception thrown if the record count is 0. So I did a work around using a try-catch in the controller to display a friendlier message if there are no records to display.

```
        public ActionResult Index(int? Id)
    {

        //Get the rosters and their attendance records
                    IQueryable<Attendances> attendances = db.Attendances
                        .Where(a => a.Enrollments_Attendance == Id)
                        .Include(e => e.Enrollments.Individuals)
                        .OrderByDescending(a => a.AttendanceDate);

                    ViewBag.EnrollmentId = Id;
        try
        {
            ViewBag.FullName = attendances.First().FullName;

        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Exception = ex;
           ViewBag.FullName = "No Attendances to display for the selected player";
        }

        return View(attendances.ToList());

    }
```

Comment: If your Model is an empty list of entities the Model.First will crash/error... FYI